# SlidingUpPanelLayout doesnot work Properly with CoordinatorLayout as first child of SlidingUpPanelLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-music-player

So when fitssystemwindow is true when it collopse it automatically increase its panel hight and when it is false it works fine . But in my project i need that true So please give me any Solution;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slideUpLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"

    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">
    <!-- This is the first child  and show main content-->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" // when this is false work fine otherwise     not
 >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

```
    <!-- this is second child and contain inside the slidingpanel -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dragView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>


 </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So please Give me solution for that or any other library which has SlideupPaneLayout from bottom to Top.